# How to make this regression table fit over two pages in overleaf

Tags: tables, fit

I have the following regression table, and it has two problems. It is too wide and too long for a single page. What are the solutions for that issue?

Thank you!

```
\caption{2021 Models}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lcccccc}
\toprule
  & N.LPC & N.CPC & N.NDP & N.BQ & N.GP & N.PPC\\
\midrule
(Intercept) & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.197}*** & \num{0.010} & \num{-0.010} & \num{0.096}*** & \num{0.069}*\\
 & (\num{0.021}) & (\num{0.023}) & (\num{0.017}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.020}) & (\num{0.028})\\
Economy & \num{0.027}*** & \num{-0.018}+ & \num{0.021}** & \num{0.008}* & \num{0.041}*** & \num{-0.038}***\\
 & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.004}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.011})\\
Environment & \num{-0.018}+ & \num{0.069}*** & \num{-0.022}** & \num{-0.005} & \num{-0.046}*** & \num{0.094}***\\
 & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.010}) & \vphantom{1} (\num{0.013})\\
Healthcare & \num{-0.022}* & \num{0.001} & \num{-0.014} & \num{-0.004} & \num{0.010} & \num{-0.002}\\
 & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.011}) & \vphantom{1} (\num{0.014})\\
Seniors & \num{0.000} & \num{0.014} & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.006} & \num{0.014} & \num{-0.030}\\
 & (\num{0.022}) & (\num{0.024}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.021}) & (\num{0.029})\\
Ethics & \num{0.045}* & \num{-0.011} & \num{0.020} & \num{0.001} & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.019}\\
 & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.020}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.025})\\
Leadership & \num{0.068}*** & \num{-0.013} & \num{0.040}** & \num{0.019}* & \num{-0.005} & \num{-0.014}\\
 & (\num{0.017}) & (\num{0.019}) & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.017}) & (\num{0.023})\\
Housing & \num{0.008} & \num{0.012} & \num{-0.011} & \num{0.007} & \num{-0.006} & \num{0.020}\\
 & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.016}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.020})\\
Election & \num{0.006} & \num{-0.040} & \num{0.017} & \num{0.018} & \num{0.007} & \num{-0.036}\\
 & (\num{0.026}) & (\num{0.029}) & (\num{0.022}) & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.026}) & (\num{0.036})\\
Covid-19 & \num{-0.009} & \num{-0.005} & \num{0.003} & \num{0.005} & \num{0.012} & \num{-0.003}\\
 & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.013})\\
Conservative & \num{0.258}*** & \num{-0.213}*** & \num{0.111}*** & \num{-0.019}*** & \num{0.037}*** & \num{-0.116}***\\
 & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.012})\\
NDP & \num{0.067}*** & \num{0.073}*** & \num{-0.041}*** & \num{-0.018}*** & \num{-0.051}*** & \num{0.041}**\\
 & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.014})\\
Bloc Québécois & \num{0.160}*** & \num{-0.048}** & \num{0.034}** & \num{-0.154}*** & \num{-0.018} & \num{0.053}**\\
 & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.015}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.018})\\
Green & \num{0.115}*** & \num{0.024} & \num{-0.003} & \num{-0.035}*** & \num{-0.079}*** & \num{-0.050}+\\
 & (\num{0.021}) & (\num{0.023}) & (\num{0.017}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.021}) & (\num{0.028})\\
None/other/D.K & \num{0.120}*** & \num{-0.077}*** & \num{0.021}* & \num{-0.017}** & \num{-0.035}** & \num{-0.068}***\\
 & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.011}) & \vphantom{1} (\num{0.015})\\
Partisanship strength & \num{0.053}*** & \num{0.049}*** & \num{0.027}** & \num{0.014}** & \num{-0.014} & \num{-0.018}\\
 & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.014})\\
Antipolitician & \num{-0.106}*** & \num{-0.084}* & \num{-0.038} & \num{-0.008} & \num{-0.072}* & \num{0.235}***\\
 & (\num{0.031}) & (\num{0.035}) & (\num{0.026}) & (\num{0.016}) & (\num{0.031}) & (\num{0.042})\\
Interest & \num{-0.002} & \num{0.019} & \num{0.014} & \num{0.001} & \num{0.015} & \num{0.164}***\\
 & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.016}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.019})\\
Woman & \num{-0.009} & \num{0.005} & \num{-0.021}*** & \num{0.004} & \num{-0.029}*** & \num{-0.003}\\
 & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.003}) & (\num{0.007}) & (\num{0.009})\\
Age & \num{0.000} & \num{0.000}* & \num{0.001}** & \num{0.000}+ & \num{0.001}*** & \num{0.002}***\\
 & (\num{0.000}) & (\num{0.000}) & (\num{0.000}) & (\num{0.000}) & (\num{0.000}) & (\num{0.000})\\
Some technical to some university & \num{-0.002} & \num{0.022}* & \num{-0.003} & \num{0.001} & \num{-0.020}* & \num{0.006}\\
 & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.013})\\
University degree & \num{-0.029}** & \num{0.045}*** & \num{0.005} & \num{0.002} & \num{-0.014} & \num{0.029}*\\
 & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.005}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.013})\\
Maritimes & \num{-0.002} & \num{-0.055}** & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.000} & \num{-0.032}* & \num{-0.005}\\
 & (\num{0.016}) & (\num{0.018}) & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.008}) & (\num{0.016}) & (\num{0.022})\\
Ontario & \num{-0.004} & \num{-0.020}+ & \num{0.008} & \num{-0.002} & \num{-0.018} & \num{0.000}\\
 & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.009}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.011}) & (\num{0.015})\\
Québec & \num{0.004} & \num{-0.033}* & \num{0.000} & \num{0.142}*** & \num{-0.007} & \num{0.091}***\\
 & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.013}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.016})\\
West & \num{0.017} & \num{0.004} & \num{-0.001} & \num{0.000} & \num{0.005} & \num{0.000}\\
 & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.014}) & (\num{0.010}) & (\num{0.006}) & (\num{0.012}) & (\num{0.017})\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & \num{10209} & \num{10209} & \num{10209} & \num{10209} & \num{10209} & \num{10209}\\
R2 & \num{0.114} & \num{0.097} & \num{0.061} & \num{0.118} & \num{0.037} & \num{0.067}\\
R2 Adj. & \num{0.112} & \num{0.095} & \num{0.058} & \num{0.115} & \num{0.034} & \num{0.064}\\
AIC & \num{5603.6} & \num{7760.4} & \num{1681.1} & \num{-8365.7} & \num{5434.9} & \num{11694.2}\\
BIC & \num{5827.8} & \num{7984.6} & \num{1905.3} & \num{-8141.6} & \num{5659.1} & \num{11918.4}\\
Log.Lik. & \num{-2770.803} & \num{-3849.208} & \num{-809.573} & \num{4213.870} & \num{-2686.474} & \num{-5816.101}\\
RMSE & \num{0.32} & \num{0.35} & \num{0.26} & \num{0.16} & \num{0.31} & \num{0.43}\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}+ p $<$ 0.1, * p $<$ 0.05, ** p $<$ 0.01, *** p $<$ 0.001}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`), which reproduce your problem.

Comment: Most importantly, we'll need to know the margins that you're using so that we know how much we need to shrink the table.  But the documentclass and packages will also be important.

Comment: BTW, instead of use ˛num b...}` for numbers of cells, you should define `S` column type for columns of  your table. Also it seems that you looking for `threeparttable` , etc.

Comment: Why is every number enclosed in a `\num` wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote,

> I have the following regression table, and it has two problems. It is too wide and too long for a single page.

While the table is quite long, it's not particularly wide. I suggest you employ a [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) environment to typeset the table.

Note that I would further recommend aligning the numbers in the six data columns on their respective decimal markers. Do get rid of the pointless and distracting `\num` wrappers, though.

The following screenshot shows just the first few lines of the `longtable` that's generated by compiling the subsequent code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} l *{6}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\caption{2021 Models}\\
\toprule
& \mc{N.LPC} & \mc{N.CPC} & \mc{N.NDP} & \mc{N.BQ} & \mc{N.GP} & \mc{N.PPC}\\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[1ex]
\toprule
& \mc{N.LPC} & \mc{N.CPC} & \mc{N.NDP} & \mc{N.BQ} & \mc{N.GP} & \mc{N.PPC}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{r@{}}{\footnotesize(cont'd on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{${}^{+}\ p< 0.1$, ${}^{*}\ p<0.05$, ${}^{**}\ p<0.01$, ${}^{***}\ p<0.001$ }\\
\endlastfoot

(Intercept) & -0.007 & 0.197{}^{***} & 0.010 & -0.010 & 0.096{}^{***} & 0.069^{*}\\
 & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.017) & (0.010) & (0.020) & (0.028)\\
Economy & 0.027{}^{***} & -0.018{}^{+} & 0.021{}^{**} & 0.008{}^{*} & 0.041{}^{***} & -0.038{}^{***}\\
 & (0.008) & (0.009) & (0.007) & (0.004) & (0.008) & (0.011)\\
Environment & -0.018{}^{+} & 0.069{}^{***} & -0.022{}^{**} & -0.005 & -0.046{}^{***} & 0.094{}^{***}\\
 & (0.010) & (0.011) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.010) &  (0.013)\\
Healthcare & -0.022{}^{*} & 0.001 & -0.014 & -0.004 & 0.010 & -0.002\\
 & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.005) & (0.011) &  (0.014)\\
Seniors & 0.000 & 0.014 & -0.007 & 0.006 & 0.014 & -0.030\\
 & (0.022) & (0.024) & (0.018) & (0.011) & (0.021) & (0.029)\\
Ethics & 0.045{}^{*} & -0.011 & 0.020 & 0.001 & -0.007 & 0.019\\
 & (0.018) & (0.020) & (0.015) & (0.009) & (0.018) & (0.025)\\
Leadership & 0.068{}^{***} & -0.013 & 0.040{}^{**} & 0.019{}^{*} & -0.005 & -0.014\\
 & (0.017) & (0.019) & (0.014) & (0.009) & (0.017) & (0.023)\\
Housing & 0.008 & 0.012 & -0.011 & 0.007 & -0.006 & 0.020\\
 & (0.015) & (0.016) & (0.012) & (0.007) & (0.014) & (0.020)\\
Election & 0.006 & -0.040 & 0.017 & 0.018 & 0.007 & -0.036\\
 & (0.026) & (0.029) & (0.022) & (0.013) & (0.026) & (0.036)\\
Covid-19 & -0.009 & -0.005 & 0.003 & 0.005 & 0.012 & -0.003\\
 & (0.009) & (0.010) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.009) & (0.013)\\
Conservative & 0.258{}^{***} & -0.213{}^{***} & 0.111{}^{***} & -0.019{}^{***} & 0.037{}^{***} & -0.116{}^{***}\\
 & (0.009) & (0.010) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.009) & (0.012)\\
NDP & 0.067{}^{***} & 0.073{}^{***} & -0.041{}^{***} & -0.018{}^{***} & -0.051{}^{***} & 0.041^{**} \\
 & (0.010) & (0.011) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.010) & (0.014)\\
Bloc Québécois & 0.160{}^{***} & -0.048{}^{**} & 0.034{}^{**} & -0.154{}^{***} & -0.018 & 0.053^{**} \\
 & (0.013) & (0.015) & (0.011) & (0.007) & (0.013) & (0.018)\\
Green & 0.115{}^{***} & 0.024 & -0.003 & -0.035{}^{***} & -0.079{}^{***} & -0.050^{+}\\
 & (0.021) & (0.023) & (0.017) & (0.010) & (0.021) & (0.028)\\
None/other/D.K & 0.120{}^{***} & -0.077{}^{***} & 0.021{}^{*} & -0.017{}^{**} & -0.035{}^{**} & -0.068{}^{***}\\
 & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.011) &  (0.015)\\
Partisanship strength & 0.053{}^{***} & 0.049{}^{***} & 0.027{}^{**} & 0.014{}^{**} & -0.014 & -0.018\\
 & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.005) & (0.011) & (0.014)\\
Antipolitician & -0.106{}^{***} & -0.084{}^{*} & -0.038 & -0.008 & -0.072{}^{*} & 0.235{}^{***}\\
 & (0.031) & (0.035) & (0.026) & (0.016) & (0.031) & (0.042)\\
Interest & -0.002 & 0.019 & 0.014 & 0.001 & 0.015 & 0.164{}^{***}\\
 & (0.014) & (0.016) & (0.012) & (0.007) & (0.014) & (0.019)\\
Woman & -0.009 & 0.005 & -0.021{}^{***} & 0.004 & -0.029{}^{***} & -0.003\\
 & (0.007) & (0.008) & (0.006) & (0.003) & (0.007) & (0.009)\\
Age & 0.000 & 0.000{}^{*} & 0.001{}^{**} & 0.000{}^{+} & 0.001{}^{***} & 0.002{}^{***}\\
 & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000) & (0.000)\\
Some techn. & -0.002 & 0.022{}^{*} & -0.003 & 0.001 & -0.020{}^{*} & 0.006\\*
 & (0.010) & (0.011) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.009) & (0.013)\\
University degree & -0.029{}^{**} & 0.045{}^{***} & 0.005 & 0.002 & -0.014 & 0.029*\\
 & (0.010) & (0.011) & (0.008) & (0.005) & (0.010) & (0.013)\\
Maritimes & -0.002 & -0.055{}^{**} & -0.007 & 0.000 & -0.032{}^{*} & -0.005\\
 & (0.016) & (0.018) & (0.014) & (0.008) & (0.016) & (0.022)\\
Ontario & -0.004 & -0.020{}^{+} & 0.008 & -0.002 & -0.018 & 0.000\\
 & (0.011) & (0.012) & (0.009) & (0.006) & (0.011) & (0.015)\\
Québec & 0.004 & -0.033{}^{*} & 0.000 & 0.142{}^{***} & -0.007 & 0.091{}^{***}\\*
 & (0.012) & (0.013) & (0.010) & (0.006) & (0.012) & (0.016)\\
West & 0.017 & 0.004 & -0.001 & 0.000 & 0.005 & 0.000\\
 & (0.012) & (0.014) & (0.010) & (0.006) & (0.012) & (0.017)\\
\midrule
Num.\ of Obs. & \mc{10209} & \mc{10209} & \mc{10209} & \mc{10209} & \mc{10209} & \mc{10209}\\
R2 & \mc{0.114} & \mc{0.097} & \mc{0.061} & \mc{0.118} & \mc{0.037} & \mc{0.067}\\
R2 Adj. & \mc{0.112} & \mc{0.095} & \mc{0.058} & \mc{0.115} & \mc{0.034} & \mc{0.064}\\
AIC & \mc{5603.6} & \mc{7760.4} & \mc{1681.1} & \mc{$-$8365.7} & \mc{5434.9} & \mc{11694.2}\\
BIC & \mc{5827.8} & \mc{7984.6} & \mc{1905.3} & \mc{$-$8141.6} & \mc{5659.1} & \mc{11918.4}\\
Log Lik. & \mc{$-$2770.803} & \mc{$-$3849.208} & \mc{$-$809.573} & \mc{4213.870} & \mc{$-$2686.474} & \mc{$-$5816.101}\\
RMSE & \mc{0.32} & \mc{0.35} & \mc{0.26} & \mc{0.16} & \mc{0.31} & \mc{0.43}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```